# How to access different date format in js

Tags: javascript, date

```
myDate2 = "6.2014"    
var date2= new Date(myDate2);
```

Here myDate2 does not contain days. It contains only year and month, I want to alert(date2), displays date error.

How to remove and output year and month.

In short I want to process date having format (mm.yyyy) instead of (dd.mm.yyyy).

Comment: What exactly do you want? You want to make `date2` have days?

Comment: Why do you want to have days if you did not define it at the beginning itself ?

Comment: @moffeltje I want only year and month.

Comment: @NikhileshKV i have input field from where only year and month comes in (mm.yyyy) format

Comment: You only want to have year and month and you state that you only have year and month. So what are you missing or what would the output you expect look like?

Comment: What is `alter(date2)`?

Comment: You will get an Invalid Date error if you don't follow the correct format. What you can do is manually add any day to your date since you're not using it anyway.

Comment: yes I have `have year and month` and I also mention `myDate2 = "6.2014"`

Comment: @NikhileshKV if I add it manually then I there will be problem for me because it need to add at least 1 day, and later output will be different, so I need only year and month and process it

Comment: guys dnt down vote, what's wrong with this question??

Comment: can you please add a jsfiddle for better understanding @yank. I did not down vote but the reason might be that your question is not very clear.

Comment: I downvoted because I have no idea what you want to achieve and what the actual problem is.

Comment: it is my php project and I need to add small js. I wrote the question making so short and simple as I can. jsfiddle is not good idea bcoz I am middle of project and many thing are related to other...... So i need to mention alot of things. But i can simplify the question more,

Comment: You need to specify exactly what you want to do and the issues you're having trying to do it. E.g. do you simply want to change "3.6.2015" to "6.2015"? Or do you want to create a Date instance for 1 June given a date string for any time in June? Creating dates by parsing with the Date constructor is **strongly** discouraged.

Comment: @RobG plz see the question once again

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to parse "6.2014" to a Date, then split the string on the period "." and pass the parts to the Date constructor in the right order (year, month, day). Subtract 1 from the month as they are zero based (0 = January, 1 = February, etc.).

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is a good resource.

```js
function parseMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[1], b[0]-1);
}

document.write(parseMY('6.2014'));
```

If you just want to reformat the string, then split it into its parts and reformat as a string:

```js
document.write('1/' + '6.2014'.split('.').join('/'))
```

There are many libraries, large and small, that can help with parsing but if you only need to deal with a single format, a two line function should suffice (or a couple more lines if validation is required).